# Failure to launch Amazon EC2 non free instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to launch a Amazon EC2 instance, in particular a GPU accelerated one. I already tried with free tiers using `t2.micro`
instances and everything is fine. When I try to select a non free one such as `g2.2xlarge` I get this error

> Launch Failed
>
> You have requested more instances (1) than your current instance limit of 0 allows for the specified instance type. Please visit http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ec2-request to request an adjustment to this limit.
> (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InstanceLimitExceeded; Request ID: 4ebf71ee-e927-42c2-8377-697a3a6cfd4b)

I'm trying to use a machine with Deep Learning AMI Ubuntu Version (but I also tried with other ones). I get this error even if I'm not running any other instance and according to the documentation the limit for these one is 5 at a time.
I have also tried to select different regions (my country is not among the choices) but it doesn't seem to change the result.

My only guess about this issue is that somehow I'm registered as a free user and I'm not allowed to use the priced services, but I'm not so sure about that.

**Edit**: I have a credit card on file on Amazon (they require it to register) and they should charge me from that.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have a credit card on file with Amazon?  They aren't going to let you run a large machine like that for free.

Comment: Yes I have and I checked for the prices (the one I need is around 0.70$ per hour). I have no problem to pay for it, but I don't know if Amazon considers me only a free user or not.

Comment: I'd contact their support then - if you've got a credit card setup then you should be able to run the machine.  Somehow they still think you're a free customer.

Comment: @stdunbar Having a CC on file, doesn't make you a non-free customer. Amazon requires a CC on file for every AWS account.

Comment: Just a side note: There is no such thing in AWS as a "free account" or a "free customer". All accounts are the same. However, there is a [free usage tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) that provides some services at no charge, mostly in the first 12 months of a new account.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Every amazon account has limits - even big corporate accounts. These limitations are set by Amazon, but you can request a limit increase. You can find your limits by clicking the Limits link in the top left hand side inside the EC2 Dashboard.

For example, if you have a `t2.micro` already running and you try to launch a `g2.xlarge` that had a limit of 1, you would not be able to since your limit of 1 has already been hit with your `t2.micro` that is running.

More Info:

- [How do I manage my AWS service limits?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/manage-service-limits/)
- [AWS FAQ Overview](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Overview)

  - Q: How many instances can I run in Amazon EC2?

To request a limit increase, submit a support request through the [AWS Support Center](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/)

To view your limits:
[image]

Comment: so what's the point in offering a service with a certain price but with a limit of `0` instances by default and thus forcing me to request to increase the limit (which I suppose will have some cost) ?

Comment: It's there as a protection. The last thing Amazon wants is people who aren't paying attention accidentally (or not) using services/features that are going to potentially cost them thousands of dollars. And no, there's no cost for requesting a limit increase. 

Even I, an employee in a company with over 5000 employees, have to request limit increases on occasion. It's quick, painless, and they generally respond very quickly.

Comment: like you :) thanks, it's the first time I'm using the Amazon EC2 service and I wasn't sure if I was missing something or not

Comment: Thanks Sathed. I viewed my limit for t1.micro was 0 but that I could create 10 t2.nano instances. That was the solution for me after following your directions to view limits. Thank you.

Comment: How long do limit increases take? Seems like it should be auto with amazon having an optional veto/review later on as opposed to "block the user until we feel like responding".

Comment: They also ask me to provide *Use case description* - so I have to convince them that I need an instance? All this AWS approach is ridiculous...

Comment: @hans - It literally takes 30 seconds... Something as simple as 'this is the instance size I need for my application' is good enough. They aren't asking for a novel, explaining your needs. That section is primarily for limits that have a hard cutoff - like static public IPs for example. If you need more than the limit of 5, you need to explain why - and for good reason. But if you don't like it, there's always Microsoft Azure or Google Cloud...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must check the limits of usage. More info in the FQA or the limits section. Amazon is not so clear on this.
[Amazon reference Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=152297)