# AWS EC2 Launch Failed Request limit exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently signed up a AWS free tier account.
I tried to launch an EC2 instance for the first time and it showed me the following error message.
Please help me.
I have already checked my request limit. It is currently 10.

[image: image description]

Comment: Have you looked at the following response:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122433/failure-to-launch-amazon-ec2-non-free-instances

Comment: Of  course, I have already looked.